# C++ 'getline' No instance of overloaded function matches argument list

Tags: c++

Trying to use getline but the error keeps saying:
No instance of overloaded function matches argument list.

```
 #include <iomanip>
 #include <string>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int lengthInput;
    int widthInput;
    ifstream fileOpening;
    fileOpening.open("testFile.txt");

while (!fileOpening.eof())
    {
//ERROR ON NEXT TWO LINES OF CODE**
        getline(fileOpening, lengthInput, ' ');
        getline(fileOpening, widthInput, ' ');
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
```

Comment: which of the overloads listed [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) are you trying to call?

Comment: Also, [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/)

Comment: What does your file actually look like? Are you actually trying to read integers, or strings?

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd parameter of `std::getline()` expects a `std::string` to write to, but in both cases you are passing in an `int` instead.  That is why you are getting the error - there really is no version of `std::getline()` that matches your code.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of `getline` is expected to be a reference to a `std::string`, not a reference to an `int`.

If you expect that the pair of values can be read from multiple lines, you can use:

```
while (fileOpening >>  lengthInput >>   widthInput)
{
   // Got the input. Use them.
}
```

If you expect that the pair of values must be read from each line, you'll have to use a different strategy.

1. Read lines of text.
2. Process each line.

```
std::string line;
while ( fileOpening >> line )
{
   std::istringstream str(line);
   if (str >>  lengthInput >>   widthInput)
   {
      // Got the input. Use them.
   }
}
```

#### Important Note

Don't use

```
while (!fileOpening.eof()) { ... }
```

See [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/).